# What is RACRoute in Mainframe?

Tags: authentication, mainframe, zos, event-viewer

What is RACRoute in Mainframe? While checking th event viewer I get an error "RACRoute AUTH failed" while trying to transfer a file to a Mainframe system. Can this be explained?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[RACROUTE](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/zos/2.4.0?topic=macros-racroute-router-interface) is a rather large topic.  The simplest answer is that you are probably not authorized by RACF to perform the action you are attempting.  If there is an error message identifier ([RACF messages](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/zos/2.4.0?topic=racf-zos-security-server-messages-codes) begin with ICF followed by a 3 digit number and then a letter) you might have some luck looking that up in the references I've provided.  There is likely an ICH message in the mainframe SYSLOG or OPERLOG that corresponds to what you are seeing in your event log.

Answer (score 0):

RACROUTE is the basic macro for authorisation checks via the SAF interface. (IBM's RACF and (I presume) Computer Associates' ACF2 and Top Secret  security products respond to authorisation requests made this way.)

Comment: Martin is correct that CA's ACF2 and Top Secret also support RACROUTE and SAF/SAF2 (System Authorization Facility).